# Add numpy array values as columns to DataFrame by unique integer

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dictionary, data-science

If I have a 3xn numpy array full of integers, how could I easily add those integers into a DataFrame like so:

input:

```
a = np.array(array([[2,10, 8],[2,9,4],[8,2,2],[8,9,10],[2,3,8]])
```

output:

Create empty DataFrame at first with columns being each unique integer from the numpy array.

In each row of this new DataFrame, I need to have each row in the numpy array appended to the unique columns. Each new integer should turn into a column separately containing the whole row.

Should look something like this before it gets to the `[2,3,8]` in the array:

```
Column:    2       4       8        9       10
R      |[2,9,4]|[8,2,2]|[2,9,4] |[8,2,2]| [2,9,4] |
O       [8,2,2]         [2,3,8]  [2,3,8]  [2,3,8]
W:      [8,9,10]
```

Since the last entry in the numpy array has a 3 in it, and 3 is not yet in the column list, I'd like a new column to be made for it.

For example if the next item in the array after `[2,3,8]` is  `[1,89,2]` then the DataFrame should now look like:

```
Column:    2       4       8        9       10         3        1     89
R      |[2,9,4]|[8,2,2]|[2,9,4] |[8,2,2]| [2,9,4] | [1,89,2] |     |     |
O       [8,2,2]         [2,3,8]  [2,3,8]  [2,3,8]
W:      [8,9,10]        [1,89,2]
        [1,89,2]        [8,9,10]
```

1 and 89 are now created as rows awaiting the next item in the numpy array.

Then columns 1, 89 and 2 would contain the next item and so on. Hopefully this is more clear.

Technically I don't care how the data is stored, I assumed a dictionary at first but the DataFrame makes more sense when I look at it now. If there is a better way with a list, a dictionary or some other function I'm not aware of, please let me know if it makes sense now.

2nd Edit:

Sorry for the confusion guys.

Comment: Your desired output is not even valid Python...

Comment: It was just an example. I have missing brackets and 5: isn't valid, apologies. Is there a way to do it as a valid dictionary though? Is the logic possible?

Comment: @JeffreyEly, please edit so that the expected output makes sense.

Comment: Even in this example, you will find yourself having duplicate keys which are not supported in python dictionaries. Or is your idea to avoid keys which have already been added?

Comment: Edited the original question with more examples. The point is to have one label, and append each new row that contains the next 3 integers into the existing label, and if it doesn't exist, add it as a new key.  Is that possible? It works when I do it manually but I can't figure out a way to do it for a whole numpy array.

Answer (score 0):

```
dict1={'2':[[2,9,4],[8,2,2]],'4': [[8,2, 2],[8,9,10]],'8':[[2,9,4],[1,89,2]],'9':[[8,2,2],[2,3,8]],'10': [[2,9,4],[2,3,8]],'3': [[1,89,2],[2,3,8]]}

df3=pd.DataFrame(dict1)
```

I think this will help you

Comment: Can you provide a bit of explanation as to why you think this will help?

Comment: Thank you but I need an actual function to add new data in that manner to either a DataFrame or a dictionary in that the '2' and the '4' etc values are coming from the actual array. Each value should have it's own label like that as I add in new data. Although I do appreciate the effort you put in. Thank you.